# htaccess remove items before a number

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to clean up duplicate pages on my website. it should be easy to remove with the .htaccess.  I'm close, but it does a redirect loop.  I do not care about anything before the "-a-" and after the domain name in my sample below.  I just need the "123".

**Sample URL:** `www.mysite.com/go-home-jimbo-a-123.html`

**I want the 301 redirect to be:** `www.mysite.com/-a-123.html`

**And I want the server to see** `www.mysite.com/location.php?a=123`

Here is what I have, but it goes into a redirect loop

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    Options +FollowSymLinks


    RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0-9]+).html$ http://www.mysite.com/-a-$2.html [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0-9]+).html$ location.php?a=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Clarification: What do you mean by "server to see ...."? Don't you want the url that's ending in 123.html in the sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a redirect loop because the target URL is also matched by the source pattern.  Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^.+-a-(\d+).html$ http://www.mysite.com/-a-$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^-a-(\d+).html$ location.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Landons is my new favorite hero.. only change was $1 at the end instead of $2.  Thanks!!!!!